What are some good additional resources when taking IBM Qiskit course?
I am a undergrad comp sci major. I have committed myself to a neuroscience PhD, hopefully computational neuro. However, I recently came across quantum computing, and see that lots of resources are being poured into it. I became motivated to do an independent research project using Qiskit, and IBM's quantum cloud computing platform. First thing's first though, i am working towards getting the IBM Qiskit certification and am doing their summer course. I am watching the online lessons provided on youtube, and a lot of the information is easily digestible and fairly intuitive. However, certain concepts like orthogonality, orthonormality, non-cloning theorem, irrelevance of global phases, projection matrices, inner products and some aspects of logic gates/ unitary operations don't make much sense to me.
I really need to learn the basics of unit vectors/ standard basis measurements, quantum logic gates/operations, and some fundamental aspects of quantum circuits. I'd like some resource that explains this on a fundamental level in a way that fits into the overall picture of understanding quantum information processing/ computing. I am about halfway through IBM's "quantum computing fundamentals" video series on youtube, so I am making good pace.
I am limited for time (about 6 months), and I am taking this course along side my summer classes, and likely will need most (if not all) of the fall semester to gain proficiency in Qiskit, and learn some basics of neural networks/ machine learning, while doing my current research project  in cognitive psychology, working part time, and engaging in college clubs. Time is clearly limited, so a book i can pick up and read for 2 to 4 hours on the weekend while i am not busy, or a video series less than 2 or 3 hours would be great. If it is easily understood by dummies, that would also be great. I plan on taking linear algebra in the fall, so that should help with certain concepts.
I would appreciate any insight or resources you point me to, thanks in advance.

The following is a selected list of resources which I used throughout the last couple of years to get myself started in Quantum Computing (QC).

Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Nielson & Chuang.
It is the de-facto standard textbook for many university courses on QC. It starts slowly with the basics of linear algebra and quantum mechanics, but becomes increasingly more difficult and complex. Furthermore, the exercises are really great to validate one's understanding of the topics covered. Use any search engine to find a free copy of it as a PDF. You can also find GitHub repositories containing solutions to some of the exercises on the web.



Introduction to Quantum Information Science by Artur Ekert.
This course was a game changer for me when I first started in QC. I've never seen someone explain difficult topics that intuitively. Moreover, it is freely available on YouTube.



Quantum Stack Exchange
Don't be surprised to find many great answers to puzzling questions here on this platform.


I've been learning QC for 6 months now and found these the most useful resources to help me understand the subject.

The lecture videos by Umesh Vazirani here
The lecture slides by John Watrous here

